# as3/flex xml toString : order of attributes in output string not always the same

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, tostring

I create an XML object in as3 and set some attributes.

```
var objectXML:XML = <test/>;
objectXML.@['one'] = '1';
objectXML.@['two'] = '2';
```

Than I get a string representation of this XML to save it somewhere:

```
objectXML.toString();
```

Once I have :

```
<test one="1" two="2"/>
```

another time I have :

```
<test two="2" one="1"/>
```

I need to have same results for the same objects to be able comparing hashes of the strings.
How can I have same order of attributes always?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible I think. That's not how XML is for and if you want this kind of behaviour, you need to use another data structure.

Comment: Unfortunatly it is not my choice XML or not.
I found that if I create XML like this:

    var objectXML:XML = <test one="1" two="2"/>;

than it prints attributes also in this order.
But this is not a guaranty.
So the only way that I see here is to make XML by hands.